# Regarding Oracle Node as a NEAR Protocol Contract implemented in Rust

Tags: rust, smartcontracts, nearprotocol, chainlink

Recently, I have been executing the implementation of this repository:

https://github.com/smartcontractkit/near-protocol-contracts

**So, everything is working fine in this...**

---

But what I want to ask in this is:

**When I executed the `request` command:**

```
near call oracle.$NEAR_ACCT request '{"payment": "10", "spec_id": "dW5pcXVlIHNwZWMgaWQ=", "callback_address": "client.'$NEAR_ACCT'", "callback_method": "token_price_callback", "nonce": "11", "data_version": "1", "data": "eyJnZXQiOiJodHRwczovL21pbi1hcGkuY3J5cHRvY29tcGFyZS5jb20vZGF0YS9wcmljZT9mc3ltPUVUSCZ0c3ltcz1VU0QiLCJwYXRoIjoiVVNEIiwidGltZXMiOjEwMH0="}' --accountId client.$NEAR_ACCT --gas 300000000000000
```

The resultant transaction was:

https://explorer.testnet.near.org/transactions/Gr4ddg77Hj1KN2EB3W7vErc6aaDq8sNPfo6KnQWkN9rm

**And then, I executed the `fulfill_request` command:**

```
near call oracle.$NEAR_ACCT fulfill_request '{"account": "client.'$NEAR_ACCT'", "nonce": "11", "data": "Nzg2"}' --accountId oracle-node.$NEAR_ACCT --gas 300000000000000
```

Then, the resultant transaction was:

https://explorer.testnet.near.org/transactions/39XZF81s9vGDzbUkobQZJufGxAX7wNrPT336S8TEnk29

---

### NOTE:

As we can see in the first command that is `request`, the **data** parameter that is passed is:

`eyJnZXQiOiJodHRwczovL21pbi1hcGkuY3J5cHRvY29tcGFyZS5jb20vZGF0YS9wcmljZT9mc3ltPUVUSCZ0c3ltcz1VU0QiLCJwYXRoIjoiVVNEIiwidGltZXMiOjEwMH0=`

When we **base64** decode that, then it comes out to be as:

`{"get":"https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/price?fsym=ETH&tsyms=USD","path":"USD","times":100}`

[image: request-data]

Similarly, in the second command that is `fulfill_request`, I passed the **data** parameter as:

`Nzg2`

When we **base64** decode that, it comes out to be as:

`786`

[image: fulfill_request-data]

And, that is also the result of the second transaction that you can see by scrolling to the midway of https://explorer.testnet.near.org/transactions/39XZF81s9vGDzbUkobQZJufGxAX7wNrPT336S8TEnk29.

We can see the result as:

`Client contract received price: "786"`

---

### So, basically what I want is:

To get the response of https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/price?fsym=ETH&tsyms=USD as the result of `fulfill_request` command, instead of hard-coded `786`.

Comment: When you execute`fulfill_request` you are simulating a call from an oracle node. In real life situation, you will send a client request via `request` command and wait for a callback from a decentralized oracle network containing the actual price (instead of hardcoded value). The problem is that Chainlink Price Feeds are not currently available on the Near Testnet as far I know.

Comment: So, can we deploy that from our end ? If yes, then can you please tell me, what should be the steps ?

Comment: You definitely can, since it's an open-source decentralized protocol, everything's on their Github. But my opinion is that you shouldn't, and maybe just try to switch to a different testnet before going live.